# Issue in displaying window as modal

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, modal-dialog

I am trying to display a `NSWindowController` class as modal sheet in a view in mac application.
the problem is that the default modal comes from up to down sliding.

```
  SettingWindowController *obj=[[SettingWindowController alloc]      initWithWindowNibName:@"SettingWindowController"];
   [NSApp beginSheet:obj.window
   modalForWindow:[self.view window]
    modalDelegate: self
   didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:)
      contextInfo: nil];
```

when I execute above code it simply opens second window controller outside the view.

[image]

How can I get the default behaviour which is the view comes from up to down by sliding.

Comment: Visible at launch" was indeed my problem, too.

Comment: Is `obj.window` nil by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  -(IBAction)showModel:(id)sender
>  {
>     obj=[[SettingWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"SettingWindowController"];
> obj.delegate=self;
> [NSApp beginSheet:obj.window
>    modalForWindow:[self.view window]
>     modalDelegate: self
>    didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:)
>       contextInfo: nil];
>    }
>  - (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
>   {
> [obj.window orderOut:self];
> ```

```
    }
-(void)showModelEnd
 {
[NSApp endSheet:obj.window];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(IBAction)showModel:(id)sender  {
    obj=[[SettingWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"SettingWindowController"]; obj.delegate=self; [NSApp beginSheet:obj.window    modalForWindow:[self.view window]
    modalDelegate: self    didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:)
      contextInfo: nil];    }



- (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
  {
[obj.window orderOut:self];
    }
-(void)showModelEnd
 {
[NSApp endSheet:obj.window];

 }
```